# How to connect three tables in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have thee tables: `Orders`, `Products`, `Products_images`.

I need to get ll orders, for this I do:

```
$orders = Order::with("products")->where("user_id", Auth::guard('api')->user()->id)->orderBy('id')->get();
```

Where `with("products")` is function in model `Order`

```
public function products()
    {

        return $this->hasOne("App\Product", "id", "product_id");
    }
```

So, I have connected two table. Also I need connect with table `Products` with table `Products_images` in this query.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a product_images function to the Products Model

```
public function product_images() { return $this->hasMany("App\ProductImage");}
```

Modify the above line's  App\ProductImage to reflect the model for your table. Then you can access all the product images records that belongs to your products by doing the following:

```
$orders = Order::with("products.product_images")->where("user_id", Auth::guard('api')->user()->id)->orderBy('id')->get();
```

Look under nested eager loading on this link : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading